# how do you do the textfield when first opened, will it give you the value of thousand (,)?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

how do you do the textfield when first opened, will it give you the value of thousand (,)?

how do I do the textfield when it will be opened the first time, will give the value of thousand (,) ?, this TextField will give (,) when I give a new input.

I was a little bit confused at the controller: priceController
because the controller can not be converted into a currency value

```
final priceController = TextEditingController();
    enabled: !_isOwned,
controller: priceController,
cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
maxLength: 11,
inputFormatters: [
    NumericTextFormatter(),
],
decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: '0',
    prefixText: 'Rp ',
    counterText: '',
    errorText:
        !_validate ? 'Biaya harus diisi' : null,
),
onChanged: (value) {
    print("VALUE $value ${value.length}");
    if (value.length > 0) {
    setState(() {
        _validate = true;
    });
    } else {
    setState(() {
        _validate = false;
    });
    }
},
)
```

Comment: You should try to post your source code as text and format it using code blocks. It is very difficult to work with screenshots.

Comment: The code you have pasted is messy. You have the declaration of a variable and then part of a TextFormField mixed in. Please check the code, separate it, and correct what is missing.

Comment: What is "(,)"? "Thousand (,)"? Do you want the TextFormField to have the value of "1000" as default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a default value on your TextFormField, you can do it in two different ways.

You can set an `initialValue` on the Widget:

```
TextFormField(
  initialValue: '1000',
),
```

Or you can define it on the `TextEditingController`:

```
TextEditingController priceController = TextEditingController(text: '1000');
```